# How to say "you added a clause in end of statment"?

Tags: clauses, irony

How do you call the act of adding a clasue to the end of a statment, which weakens it and makes it sort-of conditional?

Examples: "Nice to see you, *this time*!"

"I love it, *in a way*,

"It's not the case, *yet*" ("There are no zombies in the world, *yet*")

"There are no zombies in the world, *for now*"

"I really enjoyed it, *this time*."

"It costs only two dollars, *more or less*"

"She is cute, *when she's well fed*"

"It is funny, *if it's true*"

The clasue makes the above statements read somewhat ironically. The clasue somehow takes the statement back a bit, instead of making it conclusive.
To refer to this act, I want to say: "You phrased your statement with a (?????) in the end."
Any idea?

Is it called a "qualifier"? Or otherwise, what?

Comment: This is more a question of rhetoric than grammar. _Paraprosdokian_ is what they call it I believe.

Comment: Most of the above are downtoners, reducing the force of statement given in the independent clause. The overall effect is summed up as 'faint praise' when the statement is one praising a person / deed etc. 'More or less' is a modal adjustment to indicate lack of confidence in the accuracy of the statement. 'If it's true' actually challenges the 'facts' put forward.